# hide dropdown option on change of another dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried this, but not working fine. HTML:

```
 <div>
 <select id="color" name="color" onchange="myFunction()">                
    <option value=""> choose options </option>                
    <option value="1">AB</option>
    <option value="2">ABC</option>
    <option value="3">ABCD</option>
</select>
<select id="size" name="size" >             
    <option value=""> choose options </option>
    <option value="3" class="27">Apple </option>
    <option value="2" class="26">Orange</option>
    <option value="2" class="26">Orange</option>
    <option value="2" class="26">Orange</option>
    <option value="3" class="28">Grapes</option>
</select>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
function myFunction()
{
   $variable=$("#size").html();
   $("#size").html($variable); 
   var val=$("#color").find(":selected").val();
   $("#size option[value!="+val+"]").remove();
}
```

in place of .remove() I tried .hide() which seems to be not working. Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Hiding option is not cross browser compatible, you can disable them

Comment: But I want it back when user selects other options in first dropdown list @Satpal

Comment: Enable all option before disabling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a mix of JS and CSS.

So we "reset" the size select, by removing all the `disabled` and also the `selected`.

Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var colors = $('#color'),
        size = $('#size');
    
    colors.change(function () {
        var val = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        size.find('option').removeAttr('disabled');
        size.find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
        size.find("option[value!=" + val + "]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    })

})
```

```css
option:disabled {
    display: none;
}

option:first-child {
    display: block;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <select id="color" name="color">
        <option value="">choose options</option>
        <option value="1">AB</option>
        <option value="2">ABC</option>
        <option value="3">ABCD</option>
    </select>
    <select id="size" name="size">
        <option value="">choose options</option>
        <option value="3" class="27">Apple</option>
        <option value="2" class="26">Orange</option>
        <option value="2" class="26">Orange</option>
        <option value="2" class="26">Orange</option>
        <option value="3" class="28">Grapes</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

### Edit 1:

Using `data-group` instead of `class` or `value`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var colors = $('#color'),
        size = $('#size');
    
    colors.change(function () {
        var val = $(this).find(":selected").attr('data-group');
        size.find('option').removeAttr('disabled');
        size.find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
        size.find("option[data-group!=" + val + "]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    })

})
```

```css
option:disabled {
    display: none;
}

option:first-child {
    display: block;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <select id="color" name="color">
        <option value="">choose options</option>
        <option value="1" data-group="1">AB</option>
        <option value="2" data-group="2">ABC</option>
        <option value="3" data-group="3">ABCD</option>
    </select>
    <select id="size" name="size">
        <option value="">choose options</option>
        <option value="3" class="27" data-group="3">Apple</option>
        <option value="2" class="26" data-group="2">Orange</option>
        <option value="2" class="26" data-group="2">Orange</option>
        <option value="2" class="26" data-group="2">Orange</option>
        <option value="3" class="28" data-group="3">Grapes</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: it works!! but, instead of disabling the options, cant it be removed or something like that??

Comment: they are being disabled and then hidden by css. if you want to remove you need to "save" the ones you don't want, and then show them again. the simple solution is this one. removing them would be over complicating.

Comment: Can it be done using "class" in JS instead of "value"?

Comment: Yes. But you shouldn't be using classes for it. You can use a data attribute instead. Something like `data-group="27"` and check for that attribute.

Comment: Could you just give me a sample of that please?

Comment: Thanks a lot..!! @Joel Almeida

Answer (score 2):

You should show all options before hide.

```js
function myFunction()
{
   $variable=$("#size").html();
   $("#size").html($variable); 
   var val=$("#color").find(":selected").val();
    $("#size option").show();
   $("#size option[value!="+val+"]").hide();
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <select id="color" name="color" onchange="myFunction()">                
    <option value=""> choose options </option>                
    <option value="1">AB</option>
    <option value="2">ABC</option>
    <option value="3">ABCD</option>
</select>
<select id="size" name="size" >             
    <option value=""> choose options </option>
    <option value="3" class="27">Apple </option>
    <option value="2" class="26">Orange</option>
    <option value="2" class="26">Orange</option>
    <option value="2" class="26">Orange</option>
    <option value="3" class="28">Grapes</option>
</select>
</div>
```